# Given a stack with objects from multiple classes in it, how can you manage the objects the pop out?

Tags: java, inheritance, stack

I have a class **Father**, and two classes that extend Father, **Son1 and Son2**. I also have a Stack (lets call it myStack), and in this there are some Son1 and Son2 objects.

The user decides what objects (Son1 or Son2) he will put in the stack. When I use

`Father newFather = myStack.pop()`

either a Son1 or a Son2 will be placed in *newFather*. How can I check which one is it? Its important becouse Son1 and Son2 have different methods and I would like them in a *newSon1* or a *newSon2* variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `instanceof`

```
if(myFather instanceof Son1){
    //do something with son1
}

if(myFather instanceof Son2){
    //do something with son2
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This will make a fine addition to my collection!

Comment: @Gtomika if it's right answer please mark as correct so that other people can find easily. thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways for solving that problem. The immediate way relies on `instanceof`:

```
Father newFather = myStack.pop()
if(newFather instanceof Son1){
    Son1 mySon1 = (Son1) newFather;
    // use mySon1
}

if(newFather instanceof Son2){
    Son2 mySon2 = (Son2) newFather;
    // use mySon2
}
```

The problem is that somehow defeats polymophism. It is indeed possible and can have appropriate use cases, but when possible you should try to use overidden function:

```
class Father {
    ...
    void doProcess() {
    }
}

class Son1 extends Father{
    ...
    @Override
    public void doProcess() {
        // do Son1 processing
        ...
    }
}

class Son2 extends Father{
    ...
    @Override
    public void doProcess() {
        // do Son2 processing
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in your code you just do:

```
Father newFather = myStack.pop()
newFather.doProcess
```

Comment: just for information to other people `Son1 mySon1 = (Son1) newFather;` this is downcasting.